# Security to iframe widget from clickjacking or csrf attacks

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection, iframe-app, clickjacking

I am developing a widget which is to be hosted on a server say www.exampleserver.com.

Our client will embed this iframe to his site say www.validclient.com.
Now on embedding this widget a sms will be sent to the client's customer.

Now I was thinking about the Clickjacking By double framing in which a attcker may embed our client url in iframe. Now widget server found that request is from valid client and server shoots a SMS.

**valid client code:**

```
<html> 
// some line of code  
<iframe src="www.exampleserver.com" />
// some line of code 
</html>
```

**Attcker Code**

```
<html> 
// some line of code  
<iframe src="www.validclient.com" />  
// some line of code 
</html>
```

So I just want my server url content to be rendered on clients iframe not on attacker iframe. For this security I have used:

**Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors http://www.validclient.com**

AND

**X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM http://www.validclient.com**

This is amazing it blocks our URL on attackers iframe.

**But this is not supported by internet explorer and some other browsers.**

Please tell me any other approach for prevention of this attack which must be universal for all browser.

Thanks in advance. Hoping for a positive replies.

Comment: I think `X-Frame-Options: allow-from` is supported by IE 9+. It is also stated here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet Do you need support in older IE? That will be a tough one...